# suspected security breach

Tags: security, system

for a few days now, i'm seeing automated .log files and folders on my home folder, they are recreated even after they are deleted, couldn't make sure the source of it...

- file --> libpeerconnection.log
- folder --> t-random-on-star
- folder --> ww.example.com

is it a security breach or just bugs, how to be sure about this, how to check, how to learn more to secure and about security... any help is appreciated, thanks in advance...

here is the image of it..
http://www.anony.ws/kIMR

Comment: libpeerconnection.log is created by Chrome, it is a completely harmless known bug https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=239048 . No clue about the others but they are probably created by some software you installed. I don't think they are security breach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without further details it may be hard to pinpoint what is going on.

If you use Chromium browser there is a reported issue stating that the browser creates the **`libpeerconnection.log`** file. If this is the case, there is a temporary fix until the issue is resolved.

Edit the `/opt/google/chrome/google-chrome` file and add `cd/tmp` before the last line:

`'exec -a "$0" "$HERE/chrome"  "$@"'`

you can read more about this issue [here](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=239048).

As for the rest files again without further details it is not easy to find who is creating them. One solution is to use a program that monitors file creations - modifications, this may help narrowing down the search and the cause of the *problem*.

- [Monit](http://mmonit.com/monit/) can monitor files and directories for changes
- [Here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/13791/34691) is an answer at unix.stackexchange that describes the available options on how to monitor file creations and changes
- This [article](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-audit-files-to-see-who-made-changes-to-a-file.html) describes how to use [audit](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/raring/man8/auditd.8.html)

But again keep in mind that these files - directories may not be a security threat but like the Chromium case, a wrong design decision during application's development.